# Cypher: CREATE creates duplicate relation?

Tags: neo4j, relation

Why this query creates relation `rl` twice?

```
CREATE (n8 { id:'n8' })-[:rl {tag:'foo'}]->(n9 {id:'n9' })
```

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE` always creates, that's what the word means.  :-)

I think you probably want `MERGE` which creates a new node only if one with the same  matching properties doesn't already exist.

[Documentation on MERGE is here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html).

Reformatted, your query would be:

```
MERGE (n8 { id:'n8' })-[:rl {tag:'foo'}]->(n9 {id:'n9' })
```

Make sure to read the link above on the rules for merge, so you know when to expect how it does the matching.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a little careful with the MERGE keyword, its a PROVISIONAL feature and thus is subject to change

I would use CREATE UNIQUE for the time being
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-create-unique.html#_create_unique_relationships